# how to solve this problem:Multi Line Task: Hello World (Easy one) on codewars.com

Tags: python

[Multi Line Task: Hello World (Easy one)](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e41c408b72541002eda0982)

You are provided with the following functions:

```
t = type
k = lambda x: lambda _: x
```

Write a function `f` that returns the string `Hello, world!`.

The rules are:

- The solution should not exceed 33 lines
- Every line should have at most 2 characters

And this is my solution:

```py
s\
=\
'\
H\
e\
l\
l\
o\
,\
 \
w\
o\
r\
l\
d\
'
f\
=\
k\
(\
s\
)
```

how to improve it,my solution should run by f(''),not f().
please help me.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting puzzle. To get around the need to explicitly pass an argument to `f`, you can create a class with `t` (which is `type`), and use `k` to create a `__new__` method that returns `'Hello, world!'`. Since `__new__` is a class method, `_` would become the class object when an instance is instantiated:

```
f=t('',(),{'__new__':k('Hello, world!')})
```

so that `f()` returns: `'Hello, world!'`

Break the above code into 2 characters per line, and you get:

```
f\
=\
t(
''
,(
),
{
'\
_\
_\
n\
e\
w\
_\
_\
':
k(
'\
H\
e\
l\
l\
o\
,\
 \
w\
o\
r\
l\
d\
!'
)}
)
```

which is exactly 33 lines.

Comment: thank you for ur answer,it's very correct,now i passed .